# Force PHP request to finish no matter what?

Tags: php, request

Imagine someone drops an HTTP request to a PHP script while it's executing (e.g., the script has received all the GET and POST data and is currently processing, and the user closes their browser window).

How can I make sure PHP keeps executing until the script finishes as if the client never quit the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ignore_user_abort(TRUE)`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

You can also [set this in php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort).  Also, don't forget `set_time_limit(0)` if applicable, so your script doesn't timeout.